# Only showing the Pie Element when rendering variable width chart.js Pie Chart Elements?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

[In this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nxbgmp?file=style.css,index.ts) the pie chart elements have a variable border width (`borderWidth: [30, 1]`), and this causes chart.js to render a white circular background for the elements.  Is there a way to hide the white circular background so that only the pie elements are showing?

```
const config: ChartConfiguration = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue'],
    datasets: [
      {
        hoverOffset: 24,
        backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 9, 132)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
        borderWidth: [30, 1],
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [75, 25],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
        position: 'nearest',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: I don't know why you have set those borders if you don't want them seen, but you can hide them by setting the [`borderColor`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#styling) to the same color as the background, e.g., `borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'`. `borderColor` is [indexable](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#indexable-options), you can set different colors for each segment, and [scriptable](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#scriptable-options), if you want to use dynamic properties to compute the color.